# How can i toggle the checked state of items in a ListView?

Tags: android, listview

I know it is possible to graphically toggle the checked state of an item in a ListView. But how is this done?
I have a ListView containing several CheckedTextView items, and I've tried setting the checked state of these items by calling

```
list.setItemChecked(arg2, false);
```

and respectively

```
list.setItemChecked(arg2, true);
```

This is called in the OnItemClickedListener of my ListView, so the `arg2` is the index of the item clicked. Nevertheless, the item doesn't get checked. Is there a call to the listAdapter that I'm missing? Or what could this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What layout are you using for the ListItems? android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice?

Your [android:choiceMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android%3achoiceMode) also has to be set to either singleChoice or multipleChoice.

Comment: Choicemode is set to multipleChoice. I don't know what you mean by layout for the listItems though :o They are just CheckedTextView items, nothing more...

Comment: `mListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, mRawEndPoints); mEndPointList.setAdapter(mListAdapter);` The R.layout.list_item is only a CheckedTextView... The mRawEndPoints I use is a simple String array...

Comment: Try using android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice as the item layout.

Comment: Hmm now I have another issue... but I shall post a new question about that later...

Comment: but I wanna have my own item style. my own layout